# Overriding a woocommerce !important class

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to override woocommerce css class which by default is set to !important. How can I override this?

The Default is:

```
.woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-info, .woocommerce-message{
 padding: 1em 2em 1em 3.5em!important;}
```

I have tried the following but does not want to know:

```
main .post .entry .woocommerce-error, .woocommerce-info, .woocommerce-message{padding: 0 0 10px 0 !important;}
```

Not sure if I can change the original woocommerce stylesheet as I assume the changes I make will be overridden when plugin is updated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're overlooking the comma, there are actually **3** rules inside that line of yours, and you will have to specify it for every one of them. This should work:

```
main .post .entry .woocommerce-error, 
main .post .entry .woocommerce-info, 
main .post .entry .woocommerce-message { 
    padding: 0 0 10px 0 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to over ride default Woocommerce styles it is best to disable the stylesheets by entering the below in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
```

This way you can avoid using !important as this is bad practise and customise the shop to look as you wish.

By default Woocommerce enqueues 3 stylesheets and the above snippet will disable all of them, if you wish to disable just each one individually you can add:

```
// Remove each style one by one
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'jk_dequeue_styles' );
function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] );    // Remove the gloss
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] );     // Remove the layout
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );    // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
    return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

Please see here for more info: [Woomerce Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/)

Comment: But, why would you want to remove the *entire stylesheet*?

Comment: For complete control and customisation of the shop, I'm not saying you must do this, it is good practise to avoid using `!important` for CSS rules which is why I suggested it.

Comment: Very true, very true, but I assume OP has default stylesheets that utilise this. This solution would be using a flamethrower versus 3 mosquito's. Althought it's good to know how to do stuff like this.

Answer (score -1):

`!important` is amazingly evil and should be avoided unless you really 10000% sure you won't regret it (or maybe you want to do a simple utility class, which is okay). I never use Woo-commerce but it is such a shame for them to use `!important` rule in the css, which will be amazingly hard to make any other style that will beat that specificity.

Anyway, the best way I know is to add an ID to element that you want to override if possible, and add a new selector to improve specificity, and add `!important` rule to that selector (example below). But if not, wellllllll, I don't know.

```
#newselector{
    padding: 1em 2em 1em 3.5em!important;
}
```

`!important` is evil, I hope you won't afraid if it's suddenly eating you alive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14664104)

Comment: @morgul `the best way I know is to add an ID to element that you want to override if possible`. Isn't it an answer?  :)